# PyGame Character not moving left

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I have following issue: The character is not moving left properly. I tried to debug and saw that in the drawfrantz function the moveLeft is not true but in the while game loop it is. I have tried a lot, like setting global and more but it seems simply not to work. i followed a yt tutorial, heres the link
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Kh9s9__ywo

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

display_width = 1280
display_height = 720

x = 250
y = 250
velocity = 10
moveRIGHT = False
moveLeft = False
stepIndex = 0

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Frantz Reichts!")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

frantz_stationary = pygame.image.load("assets/frantz/trash_ting3.png")

frantz_going_left = [None]*10
for indexofpic in range(1,9):
    frantz_going_left[indexofpic-1] = pygame.image.load("assets/frantz/L" + str(indexofpic) + ".png")
    indexofpic = (indexofpic + 1)

frantz_going_right = [None]*10
for picindex in range(1,9):
    frantz_going_right[picindex-1] = pygame.image.load("assets/frantz/R" + str(picindex) + ".png")
    picindex = (picindex + 1)





# Images #
stage1full = pygame.image.load("assets/WholeStage.png")
karavane = pygame.image.load("assets/Karavane.png")

def DrawFrantz():
    global stepIndex
    if stepIndex >= 8:
        stepIndex = 0
    if moveLeft == True:
        screen.blit(frantz_going_left[stepIndex], (x, y))
        stepIndex += 1
    elif moveRIGHT == True:
        screen.blit(frantz_going_right[stepIndex], (x, y))
        stepIndex += 1
    else:
        screen.blit(frantz_stationary, (x, y))

while(True): #Game Loop
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(stage1full, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(karavane, (0,0))

    DrawFrantz()

    userInput = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if userInput[pygame.K_a]:
        x -= velocity
        moveLeft = True
        moveRIGHT = False
        
    if userInput[pygame.K_d]:
        x += velocity
        moveLeft = False
        moveRIGHT = True
    else:
        moveLeft = False
        moveRIGHT = False
        stepIndex = 0


    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

    pygame.time.delay(100)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: Not sure but just a quick note: you don't need to update the counter in those 'for' loops at the beginning, maybe give it a try without?

Comment: Also inside your 'DrawFrantz' function, you've called global stepIndex but perhaps you missed to call moveLeft and moveRight global as well?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it but I guess you need an `elif` instead of an `if`:

```
userInput = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if userInput[pygame.K_a]:
    x -= velocity
    moveLeft = True
    moveRIGHT = False
    
elif userInput[pygame.K_d]: # <- here elif instead of if
    x += velocity
    moveLeft = False
    moveRIGHT = True
else:
    moveLeft = False
    moveRIGHT = False
    stepIndex = 0
```

otherwise the `else` at the end will reset the boolean `moveLeft` to `False`even if you are pressing the `K_a` button.

Comment: Thank you it worked, haven't thought of that

Answer (score 1):

@Valentino's answer is correct. However, I suggest simplifying the code.

Set a `move_x` variable that is 1 when <kbd>right</kbd> is pressed and -1 when <kbd>left</kbd> is pressed. is pressed. If none or both buttons are pressed, the variable is 0. Use the  `move_x` variable to set `moveLeft`, `moveRIGHT` and to change `x` and `stepIndex`:

```py
userInput = pygame.key.get_pressed()
move_x = userInput[pygame.K_d] - userInput[pygame.K_a]

moveLeft = move_x < 0
moveRIGHT = move_x > 0
x += move_x * velocity
if move_x = 0:
    stepIndex = 0
```